# Cylinder, attach semi-sphere, For which values r and h is the surface O of the complete body minimal, if the volume V is given?

Tags: geometry, surfaces, spheres

On top of a circular cylinder (radius r, height h) we attach a semi-sphere (radius r, center on the cylinder axis). For which values r and h is the surface O of the complete body minimal, if the volume V is given?

I can't imagine such an image even, anyone could help please?

Comment: http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.14/h/ami1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a cylinder of base radius $r$ , and height $h$. and a the top you attach a hemi-sphere of radius $r$, so total volume is

$V = \text{constant} = \pi \left( r^2 h + \dfrac{2}{3} r^3 \right) $

The above equation sets a relation between $r$ and $h$.

The total surface area (which we want to minimize) is given by

$ A(r, h) = 2 \pi r h + \pi r^2 + 2 \pi r^2 = \pi ( 2 r h + 3 r^2 ) $

From the equation of the volume we can solve for $h$ in terms of $r$.

$ h = \dfrac{ \left(\dfrac{V}{\pi} \right) - \frac{2}{3} r^3 }{ r^2 } = \dfrac{V}{\pi} \left(\dfrac{1}{r^2} \right) - \dfrac{2}{3}  r$

Plug this into the equation of the surface area:

$A(r) = \pi \left( \dfrac{2V}{\pi} \left( \dfrac{1}{r} \right) + \dfrac{5}{3} r^2 \right) $

Now, we just need to differentiate $A(r)$ with respect to $r$

$A'(r) = \pi \left( \dfrac{2V}{\pi} \left( -\dfrac{1}{r^2} \right) + \dfrac{10}{3} r \right ) $

Setting $A'(r) = 0$, and solving for $r$, we get

$ r^3 = \dfrac{3 V}{5 \pi} $

so that the area minimizing $r$ is given by

$ r = \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{3V}{5 \pi}} $

And knowing this, we can determine the corresponding value of the height $h$.

Plug $r$ in the formula for $h$

$h = \dfrac{5}{3} r - \dfrac{2}{3} r = r $

Comment: you don't have the correct expression for the area after substituting for $h$. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @DavidQuinn Thanks.  I'll check it.